# Select multiple elements with BeautifulSoup and manage them individually

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse a webpage of poetry. The poetry is separated into `h3` for poem title, and `.line` for each line of the poem. I can get both elements and add them to a list. But I want to manipulate the `h3` to be uppercase and indicate a line break, then insert it into the lines list.

```
    linesArr = []
    for lines in full_text:
        booktitles = lines.select('h3')
        for booktitle in booktitles:
            linesArr.append(booktitle.text.upper())
            linesArr.append('')
        for line in lines.select('h3, .line'):
            linesArr.append(line.text)
```

This code appends all book titles to the beginning of the list, then continues getting the `h3` and `.line` items. I have tried inserting code like this:

```
    linesArr = []
    for lines in full_text:
        for line in lines.select('h3, .line'):
            if line.find('h3'):
                linesArr.append(line.text.upper())
                linesArr.append('')
            else:
                linesArr.append(line.text)
```

Comment: Could you provide the URL, please?

Comment: without the url or what the `full_text` is storing, it's tough to offer you the correct solution.

Comment: Here's the URL: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CT/1:1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do, but here with this way you can get an array with the title in upper case and all your line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf8

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CT/1:1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h3')
full_lines = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'line'})

linesArr = []
linesArr.append(title.get_text().upper())
for line in full_lines:
    linesArr.append(line.get_text())

# Print full array with the title and text
print(linesArr)

# Print text here with line break
for linea in linesArr:
    print(linea + '\n')
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer, but thank you. making two separate soup calls was a good idea.